# Phaser spritesheet loading rotated 90cw

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I used TexturePacker to create a spritesheet with a JSON file, this is my bit of code:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update
});

function preload() {
    game.load.atlas('seyan_f_torch', '../sprite_hashes/seyan_f_torch.png', '../sprite_hashes/seyan_f_torch.json');
};

function create() {
    var seyan_f_torch = game.add.sprite(20, 20, 'seyan_f_torch', '00219001.png');
    console.log(Phaser.Animation.generateFrameNames('00', 219016, 219023, ''));
    seyan_f_torch.animations.add('walk-s', Phaser.Animation.generateFrameNames('00', 219016, 219023, '.png'), 10, true);
    // seyan_f_torch.animations.play('walk-s');
};

function update() {

};
```

Everything works fine and this is the bit of json code:

```
"00219001.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":782,"y":139,"w":37,"h":58},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":39,"y":67,"w":37,"h":58},
    "sourceSize": {"w":120,"h":240},
    "pivot": {"x":0.5,"y":0.5}
},
```

But when the image loads it loads like this:

[image]

Any information on how to get it to turn the right way would be great thanks.

Edit:

It appears Phaser does not have support for rotated atlas so if you use Texture pack in my case, uncheck rotate images. 
https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/2359#issuecomment-189161540

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Phaser forum](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/1582-horizontal-sprite-flip/#comment-10705):

```js
// Set anchor to the center of your sprite
sprite.anchor.setTo(.5, .5);

// Invert scale.x to flip left/right
sprite.scale.x *= -1;

// Invert scale.y to flip up/down
sprite.scale.y *= -1;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll mark this as an answer because it's a possible solution but after hearing feedback from Photonstorm it appears they do not support rotated atlas maps.